# Why does this sort function do not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

want to sort html select by it's options text.

```
$(function() {
        var options = $('#buybox select[name="group[2]"] option');

        var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
            return {
                t: $(o).text(),
                v: o.value
            };
        }).get();

        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            //return a.t > b.t ? 1 : a.t < b.t ? -1 : 0;// numeric
            var sizes = { "XS" : 0 , "S" : 1, "M" : 2, "L" : 3, "XL" : 4, "2XL" : 5};
            console.log(sizes);
            console.log(a.t);
            console.log(b.t);
            console.log(sizes[a.t]);
            console.log(sizes[b.t]);
            return sizes[a.t] > sizes[b.t] ? 1 : sizes[a.t] < sizes[b.t] ? -1 : 0;
        });

        options.each(function(i, o) {
            o.value = arr[i].v;
            $(o).text(arr[i].t);
        });


    });
```

numeric sorting works just fine. but the property name a.t and b.t are undefined.
What's wrong here?

thanks

HTML Select

```
    select name="group[2]" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="width: 300px;">
<option selected="selected" value="7">L</option>
<option value="8">XL</option>
<option value="9">2XL</option>
<option value="35">M</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try `var options = $('#buybox select[name="group\\[2\\]"] option');`

Comment: @LShetty: thanks but the selector works.

Answer (score 0):

You're complicating it **a lot**

```
var sizes  = ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "2XL"],
    select = $('#buybox select[name="group[2]"]');

$('option', select).sort(function (a, b) {
    return sizes.indexOf($(a).text()) - sizes.indexOf($(b).text());
}).appendTo(select);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1y24sye8/2/)

Comment: Thank's, that's brilliant! And so much shorter ;-) but the fault in my solution was that i have to trim the options-text. But your's is so much better.